# GetTopLevelParent only return one instance

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, message

When my application have multiple Window.
and GetTopLevelParent only returned one result.
Did the following code are act on all window?

```c++
HWND tParent = CWnd::GetTopLevelParent(); // Get a valid handle  now.
if (tParent != NULL)
{
    cwnd->SendMessageToDescendants(WM_INITIALUPDATE, 0, 0, TRUE, TRUE);
}
```

Comment: According to the documentation of the functions you are using it should have done exactly that. Is there any reason why you believe it to be not so, or have you wrote some code that shows that this does not happen?

Comment: Windows are not like humans - you don't need two of them to have children.

Comment: Your syntax gets you in trouble.  You make it look like a static function, it is not.  Use `this->GetTopLevelParent()`.

Comment: Where did `cwnd` come from? The code snippet you posted is fairly awkward. In fact, it doesn't even compile. A `CWnd*` cannot be converted to a `HWND`. Please post real code.